# Load .JSON data into A-Frame

Tags: html, json, aframe

Load an external .JSON data file containing text into the a-text.

```
<a-scene>
 <a-text text="foo;"></a-text>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a custom component, which will parse the JSON object, and set the a-text value as one of the JSON data objects:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('jsonreader'{
  init:function(){
    let jsonObj = JSON.parse('urlToJSONFile');
    this.el.setAttribute('value',jsonObj.text);
  }
}
```

then just add the component:

```
<a-text jsonreader></a-text>
```

I've got a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/7a87dnr7/. I took a random JSON file from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).

---

By the way, either use the text primitive:

```
<a-text value='' color=''></a-text>
```

Or use text as a component:

```
<a-entity text="value:;color:;"></a-entity>
```

You seem to mix them up, I'm not sure if it won't generate some errors in the long run ( as the primitive already consists of the text component ).